# Mail Transfer Agent for W2K3 Server Recommendations

Tags: windows-server-2003, email-server

I need to set up a mail transfer agent on our server and am looking for a good free one.

I need it to handle multiple domains and allow forwarding of emails for those domains to other email addresses (ie. no mailboxes)

I did some searching and Exim seems to be reasonable ... anyone have experience with this or have other recommendations?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the Microsoft IIS 6.0 SMTP Server that is included with Windows Server 2003?

- [SMTP Server Setup (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/e4cf06f5-9a36-474b-ba78-3f287a2b88f2.mspx?mfr=true)
- [SMTP Administration (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/4b115fcd-3f3b-4d3d-8d12-f51d2e996a12.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 0):

I have used Exim in the past for a multiple-domain mail server with all sorts of forwarding and mailboxes, etc. Very good experience, I can only recommend it. Specifically when used in combination with ClamAV (Antivirus) and SpamAssassin (not sure whether these two are available for MS Windows, our mail server ran Debian GNU/Linux).

Depending on your requirements, Exim can be a tad complicated at first, but it is very powerful, highly configurable and extremely versatile. And for the admin side of it, you may as well have a look at vexim, a web-based admin interface.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I gotta go with the IIS option